# How would I go about doing this? Java Inheritance

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

What I am trying to achieve is a bit complicated to explain especially for a person like me but basically, I will try to explain it as much as I can.

Note: Don't worry about the encapsulation since this is just a prototype.

What I want to achieve is having a class that extends the PersistenceData class to hold more information in the extended class and use it in corresponding to the PlayerManager class as it's specific to that. Although that code results in an expected error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.javatest.PersistenceData cannot be cast to com.javatest.PlayerData
```

So my question is, how would I be able to achieve something like this? I don't know what this pattern is called but perhaps there is an alternative to this.

Here is the hierarchy of my data classes:

```
public class PersistenceData
{
    public String ID;
    public String Name;

    public PersistenceData(String id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
}

public class PlayerData extends PersistenceData
{
    public int CharacterCount;

    public PlayerData(String id)
    {
        super(id);
    }
}
```

And here is my class that stores these pieces of data:

```
public abstract class Manager
{
    protected final Map<String, PersistenceData> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void Load()
    {
        //Loading indefinite values from MYSQL here.
        PersistenceData persistenceData = new PersistenceData("testid");
        persistenceData.Name = "testname";
        dataMap.put("testid", persistenceData);
    }

    public Map<String, PersistenceData> GetDataMap()
    {
        return dataMap;
    }

    public Map<String, PersistenceData> GetDataMapCopy()
    {
        return new HashMap<>(dataMap);
    }
}


public class PlayerManager extends Manager
{
    private static PlayerManager Instance;

    public static PlayerManager GetInstance()
    {
        return Instance == null ? Instance = new PlayerManager() : Instance;
    }

    private PlayerManager()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void Load()
    {
        super.Load();

        PlayerData playerData = (PlayerData) dataMap.get("testid");
        playerData.CharacterCount = 3;

        System.out.println("ID: " + playerData.ID);
        System.out.println("Name: " + playerData.Name);
        System.out.println("Character Count: " + playerData.CharacterCount);
    }
}
```

Basically the main question is, how do I instantiate a subclass based on the superclass without knowing what kind of subclass is going to be instantiated. I tried to use generics but doesn't seem to work.

```
public abstract class Manager <T extends PersistenceData>
{
protected final Map<String, T> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

public void Load()
{
    //Loading indefinite values from MYSQL here.
    T persistenceData = new T("testid");
    // T extends from PersistenceData. So it needs to have a constructor of atleast 1 argument.
    persistenceData.Name = "testname";
    dataMap.put("testid", persistenceData);
}

public Map<String, T> GetDataMap()
{
    return dataMap;
}

public Map<String, T> GetDataMapCopy()
{
    return new HashMap<>(dataMap);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've moved the relevant parts of your code into your post directly as opposed to having it simply linked as off-site code is frowned upon for various reasons (such as the case where the other site goes down, making your question unusable for future visitors). Otherwise, this was a fairly good question due to it showing the problem and intent clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a subclass instance to a superclass instance, but you can do something like this:

```
PersistenceData foo = new PlayerData("foo");
```

Later on, you can use `foo` as a `PlayerData` instance by simply casting it.

Comment: Don't you mean "you cannot cast a super class into a sub class". You most certain cast a subclass into its super class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is, if I do that, I lose the data I loaded onto the PersistenceData class. PersistenceData is a class that loads general data regarding each Manager classes whereas PlayerData contains information of the data inside PersistenceData as well as have it's own information which is being handled inside the PlayerManager class that is extending the Manager class.

Answer (score 0):

Alright figured it out. Not sure if it's the most efficient way but it works. Basically I had to generalized the Manager.java class and I use the subclass on the PlayerManager.java to make this work. There is probably better ways to do this that I am not aware of.

Manager.java

```
public abstract class Manager <T extends PersistenceData>
{
    protected final Map<String, T> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void Load(T data)
    {
        data.Name = "TestName";

        dataMap.put(data.ID, data);
    }

    public Map<String, T> GetDataMap()
    {
        return dataMap;
    }

    public Map<String, T> GetDataMapCopy()
    {
        return new HashMap<>(dataMap);
    }
}
```

PlayerManager.java

```
public class PlayerManager extends Manager<PlayerData>
{
    private static PlayerManager Instance;

    public static PlayerManager GetInstance()
    {
        return Instance == null ? Instance = new PlayerManager() : Instance;
    }

    private PlayerManager()
    {

    }

    public void Load()
    {
        PlayerData playerData = new PlayerData("testid");

        super.Load(playerData);

        playerData.CharacterCount = 3;

        System.out.println("ID: " + playerData.ID);
        System.out.println("Name: " + playerData.Name);
        System.out.println("Character Count: " + playerData.CharacterCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would make all the methods abstract so that you force derived classes to have different specific implementations. As it is, `Load(T data)` will work for `PlayerManager` but will not return the correct data.